# How can I see how much I have remaining of a rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

How can I see how much work is left on a rebase while it's in progress?

I.e. I want to see how much work git has left to check.

Comment: This doesn't sound related to conflicts, it sounds like the OP wants to know what step is currently being executed.

Comment: @EdwardThomson You are correct, sir.

Comment: @jubobs, when the rebase makes a lot of progress, it shows a counter such as (10/35), so it must be possible, the information exists

Answer (score 27):

### Starting with `git` version 2.26

Here's the shell command that prints the rebase progress:

```
( RMD="$( git rev-parse --git-path 'rebase-merge/' )" && N=$( cat "${RMD}msgnum" ) && L=$( cat "${RMD}end" ) && echo "${N} / ${L}" ; )
```

Sample output will be like

```
4 / 7
```

You can modify the last `echo` command parameter to print it using the format you like.

### For `git` with versions that are <= 2.25

```
( RaD="$( git rev-parse --git-path 'rebase-apply/' )" && N=$( cat "${RaD}next" ) && L=$( cat "${RaD}last" ) && echo "${N} / ${L}" ; )
```

Comment: Just a note: those commands will only work on Linux. Might be useful to also just list the directories as well.

Comment: @MattVukomanovic , I am not quite sure what exactly you mean by "only work on Linux". It works in GNU+Linux, macOS and windows. It works perfectly in ZSH and Bash. I do use ZSH in Cygwin. And Bash as shell that comes with "Git for Windows".

Comment: ah I don't use git bash on windows I use cmd.exe with the linux tools included in the system folder, so that is the confusion.

Comment: @MattVukomanovic, I also don't quite use Bash for Windows. At least not the shell itself. I do use Cygwin (yes, its a little bit slow :( ) which is much better than anything else in windows as for me.

Answer (score 20):

You are probably looking for this information for a normal rebase instead of an interactive rebase.

That information isn't shown for non interactive rebases. However you can find it out by looking in your **rebase-apply** directory.

In that directory there is all the information you need.
Specifically if you are running with the default .git directory location you can find it out by running these commands

```
cat .git/rebase-apply/next
cat .git/rebase-apply/last
```

If you want to know the commit which is currently being applied then you can use the following

```
cat .git/rebase-apply/original-commit
```

And if you want to see the actual patches which are being applied then you can look at the numbered files in .git/rebase-apply

Comment: Starting with version 2.26 of `git` the `git rebase $Onto $Branch` command now triggers interactive rebase by default. This answer is not valid for that case anymore. Please see my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292015/2753851 for a proper solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), your prompt will show something like `|REBASE-i (x/y)` when resolving a conflict during an interactive rebase, where `x` is rebase step out of `y` where the conflict occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
git rebase --edit-todo
```

Answer (score 1):

`git status`

Example content:

```
On branch xxx
Your branch and 'origin/xxx' have diverged,
and have 4 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" if you want to integrate the remote branch with yours)

No commands done.
Next commands to do (5 remaining commands):
   pick d33eb3d Add 3ds not performed case -
   edit c58cad6 Refactor extract method to update models
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'xxx' on '18cc67c'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: This solved my instance of this question - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take a look at it and you're using Bash, you can run: `__git_ps1`. It will display something similar to `(feature/avarias|MERGING)(base)`, but concerning rebase. This string is meant to compose your prompt by assigning it to variable `PS1`.